# Python fit and chi square comparison

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I want to know which functions fits better to my data by calculating the chi square value and then compare it.

The data i have could like either like a gaussian or kind of like an horizontal line, so my goal would be to fit each time my data (using scipy.curve fit) to both functions and then calculate the chisquare value (using scipy.stats), but can i directly compare both values and take the 'lowest' one as both functions have the same number of points but different parameters (hence not the same df): 4 parameters for my gaussian and 1 for my horizontal line ?

[image: gaussian like]
[image: horizontal like]
[image: test fitting]
[image: test fitting 2]
[image: using matt's answer]

```
def horiz(x,c):
    return np.full_like(x, c)
```

```
#Define the Gaussian function
def gauss(x, H, A, x0, sigma):
    return H + A * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))
```

example of code below:

```
p0_c = [moy]
popt_c, pcov = curve_fit(horiz, x, Smooth_data, p0 = p0_c)
fit_c = horiz(x, *popt_c)
chi_c, p_c = stats.chisquare(Counts_list[i], fit_c )
```

end.

Comment: Yes i've already used the savitsky golay algorithm but the problem is the same, do you know if i can compare both chi square values?

Comment: Ok, do you have some ideas or insights about the chi square for goodness of fit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like the [Bayesian Information Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) (BIC) for model selection, which accounts for the different numbers of parameters in each model with a penalty factor for more parameters.

Mocking up a version of your example, this could be done with the following steps.

1. Set up model functions and generate some simulated data containing a Gaussian "bump".

   ```py
   import numpy as np
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
   from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

   def gauss(x, H, A, x0, sigma):
       return H + A * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

   def horiz(x,c):
       return np.full_like(x, c)

   # generate some data containing a Gaussian bump
   n = 10_000  # number of data points
   x = np.linspace(0, 1_000_000, n, dtype=float)

   # random Gaussian noise
   y = np.random.randn(n) * 5e-8

   # Gaussian bump parameters
   sigma = 30_000
   x0 = 400_000
   H = 0
   A = 4.5e-7

   y += gauss(x, H, A, x0, sigma)
   ```
2. Use `curve_fit` to get a best fit, maximum likelihood, model (I've had to scale the parameters to get the fitting to work reasonably).

   ```py
   # scale factors
   scaleamp = 1e8
   scalerange = 1e-5

   # initial parameter guesses
   iniguess = (0.1e-7 * scaleamp, 1e-7 * scaleamp, 350000.0 * scalerange, 10000.0 * scalerange)

   # fit Gaussian bump model
   gaussfit = curve_fit(gauss, x * scalerange, y * scaleamp, p0=iniguess)

   # fit horizontal line model
   linefit = curve_fit(horiz, x, y * scaleamp, p0=(0.0,))
   ```
3. Generate the best fit models and calculate the (log)likelihood for that model given the data (for the likelihood function, because we don't have an estimate of the uncertainty in the data, we can use the Student's t-like distribution defined in Eqn 3.38 in [Sivia](http://aprsa.villanova.edu/files/sivia.pdf) on pg. 53).

   ```py
   Hf, Af, x0f, sigmaf = gaussfit[0]

   # rescale best fit parameters to generate the Gaussian model
   bestgaussfit = gauss(x, Hf / scaleamp, Af / scaleamp, x0f / scalerange, sigmaf / scalerange)

   # get log likelihood
   logLgauss = -((n - 1) / 2) * np.log(np.sum((y - bestgaussfit)**2))

   # generate the best fit horizontal line model
   bestlinefit = horiz(x, linefit[0][0] / scaleamp)

   # get log likelihood
   logLhoriz = -((n - 1) / 2) * np.log(np.sum((y - bestlinefit)**2))
   ```
4. Generate the BIC for both models.

   ```py
   ngaussparams = 4  # number of Gaussian model parameters
   bicgauss = ngaussparams * np.log(n) - 2 * logLgauss

   nlineparams = 1  # number of parameters for the flat line
   bicline = nlineparams * np.log(n) - 2 * logLhoriz
   ```

With the BIC, the model with the lower number is the preferred model. In this case the BIC for the Gaussian model is a lot lower (by about 16000 for the data I generated).

Comment: Hi first of all thanks for your help Matt. I've tested it and it works really nicely for the gaussian but whenever i get rid of the line `y += gauss(x, H, A, x0, sigma)` in order to only simulate a noisy signal i do not have much difference between bicgauss and bicline, they are really close but sometimes (rarely bicgauss is even smaller). But i'll work with it and try to find a criteria so that when the 2 bics are really close (do not know yet if i should work with % differences) then it is a line.

Comment: While you're here do you know 'a lot' about chi square methods ? Especially with the scipy library on python

Comment: Yes, it's useful to do some empirical testing to work out a reasonable BIC threshold for distinguishing between models. It's easy in very clear cut cases, but becomes somewhat more tricky when your signal is weak - there are hand-wavy rules of thumb that you can apply to Bayes factors, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor, but some empirical evaluation is usually best.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with the chi-squared methods in scipy. I'm more familiar with Bayesian inference methods. I'd recommend looking into methods to calculate the Bayesian evidence (marginal likelihood) from which you can calculate the odds between the models. Python packages such as dynesty (https://dynesty.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) are good for this. This will incorporate, through the priors, a penalty for more complex models. It will be more computationally intensive though, so it depends how much data you have and how quickly you need an output.

Comment: Even with methods that calculate the Bayesian odds, it's still useful to do some empirical evaluation, as the odds can be greatly influenced by your choice of prior (this is not so problematic when the prior is a clear cut thing based on physical/methodological limits).

Comment: Okok i see i'll look into all of this the as it will certainly help me a lot, i stil have a quick question (i'll edit my question) --> on the last picture we can see that i do a moving average that i then fit using some of your code and the bic gauss = -475.390924411268 while the line one is: -478.4130459458398, they are really close, of course it depends on the size of the interval i choose to do my average

Comment: In your final picture it seems to have got a best fit Gaussian bump that has a negative amplitude and a very broad sigma. If you only ever expect that Gaussian bumps to be positive, you could play around with setting bounds for `curve_fit` such that it only allows positive amplitudes. For example, if you just want to make sure all bump amplitudes are positive (and x0 and sigma are positive too, while `H` is allowed to be anything), you could have `bounds=([-np.inf, 0, 0, 0], [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, no.inf])`.